# How can I get this textfield and dropdown menu working to do what I want?

Tags: java, swing, drop-down-menu, textinput

I don't expect anyone to do the work for me, but I'm having trouble finding the exact answers to my questions researching on my own. I'm trying to have a text field where the user must input an integer between 1 and 3 and then a drop down menu to pick a flavor (would like the drop down selection to either work as the way to submit or just get the menu itself to stay selected). After submission I want a window to pop up with a painted ice cream cone that changes color based on the flavor and the number of scoops to also be accurate to the user's input.

I have been trying to work with JOptionPanel as I thought maybe that in combination with some sort of ActionListener set up would do the trick for me, but I can't seem to find the how-to or advice I need to get the job done that way.

```
public void createGUI()
{
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Container window = getContentPane();
        window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    GridLayout mainLayout = new GridLayout(2,1);
    GridLayout topLayout = new GridLayout(1,2);
    GridLayout menuLayout = new GridLayout(6,2);

    JLabel storeFront = new JLabel("Ice Cream Shop");
    JLabel orderHere = new JLabel("Order Here");

    ImageIcon storeImage = new ImageIcon("storefront.jpeg");
        JLabel store = new JLabel(storeImage);

    ImageIcon flavorsImage = new ImageIcon("flavors.jpeg");
        JLabel flavors = new JLabel(flavorsImage);

    JTextField numberScoops = new JTextField(5);


    JMenuBar flavorMenu = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu flavorIceCream = new JMenu();

        JMenuItem chocolate = new JMenuItem("Chocolate");
        JMenuItem vanilla = new JMenuItem("Vanilla");
        JMenuItem strawberry = new JMenuItem("Strawberry");
        flavorIceCream.add(chocolate);
        flavorIceCream.add(vanilla);
        flavorIceCream.add(strawberry);

        flavorMenu.add(flavorIceCream);

    JPanel iceCreamShop = new JPanel();
        iceCreamShop.setBackground(Color.gray);
        iceCreamShop.add(store, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel iceCreamMenu = new JPanel();
        iceCreamMenu.setBackground(Color.gray);
            JPanel menuPanel = new JPanel();
                menuPanel.setBackground(Color.gray);
                menuPanel.setLayout(menuLayout);

                menuPanel.add(new JLabel("Chocolate"));
                menuPanel.add(new JLabel("$2.00/scoop"));
                menuPanel.add(new JLabel("Vanilla"));
                menuPanel.add(new JLabel("$2.00/scoop"));
                menuPanel.add(new JLabel("Strawberry"));
                menuPanel.add(new JLabel("$2.25/scoop"));
                menuPanel.add(new JLabel("How Many Scoops?"));
                menuPanel.add(numberScoops);
                menuPanel.add(new JLabel("what flavor?"));
                menuPanel.add(flavorMenu);
                menuPanel.add(new JButton("clear"));
                menuPanel.add(new JButton("submit"));
        iceCreamMenu.add(menuPanel);

    JPanel iceCreamOrder = new JPanel();
        iceCreamOrder.setLayout(topLayout);
        iceCreamOrder.add(iceCreamShop);
        iceCreamOrder.add(iceCreamMenu);

    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout (mainLayout);
        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.gray);
        mainPanel.add(iceCreamOrder);
        mainPanel.add(flavors, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    window.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

}
```

Comment: [How to Use Combo Boxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html), [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html); [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you so much for pointing me toward combo boxes, that was the thing I needed to stumble upon and just wasn't getting to on my own!